# MSVC 2015 /Wall has lots of not useful messages

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Even if I have an empty program save for include string, even if I suppress warnings around includes, I still get lots of warnings.

To reproduce:

```
# CMakeLists.txt

add_executable(main main.cpp)

# All warnings, and treat as errors
if(MSVC)
    set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Wall /WX")
endif()
```

---

```
// main.cpp

#pragma warning(push, 0) // suppress warnings from dependencies
#include <string>
#pragma warning(pop)

int main()
{
}
```

Even with just this, I get pages of warnings, the first of which is...

```
main.cpp(8): warning C4710: 'int swprintf_s(wchar_t *const ,const std::size_t,const wchar_t *const ,...)': function not inlined
```

Is this expected? Or did I do something wrong?

Should I cherry pick warnings to suppress, and supress them in every file I write?

Alternatively, should I cherry pick which warnings to enable? But that could become a tediously long list, which I would have to maintain as new checks become available.

Comment: Don't think warnings aren't useful. Fix all of them to improve the quality of your code actually.

Comment: Some warnings cannot be suppressed. However, is the small main.cpp an example that would reproduce this? That sounds wrong.

Comment: Generally, you can compile with `/W4` to get most of the warnings.  The additional ones you get with `/Wall` are informative.  You can enable all warnings, then selectively disable the ones you don't need (like the C4710 example).

Comment: @AndyG Yes, this small main.cpp reproduces this. Feel free to double check. If it turns out I did something wrong that I can fix, that would actually be good news.

Comment: @JeffM: Yeah, it's reproducible. It goes away if /W4 is set, so it appears that /WX ignores `#pragma warning(push` I'll see if the docs say anything

Comment: He's not kidding. Fired his code up in VS 2010, put another brick in the `\Wall`, and there are thousands of warnings coming out of the MSVC standard library.

Comment: `/Wall` has way too many useless warnings that I personally don't find it useful. It "warns" about innocuous stuff like adding padding between struct members. Really? Since when is implicit padding between struct members a programming error? Or even a styling error?

Comment: If you remove `pragma warning(pop)` then it works, so there's something up with perhaps code injected by the preprocessor.

Comment: @AndyG I don't think /WX ignores `#pragma warning(push` because if I take that out, then I get several *more* pages of warnings. So it seems to be doing *some* good, just not enough for an otherwise null program to be warning free.

If I remove `#pragma warning(pop)`, wouldn't that leave all warnings suppressed for the entire file? Which defeats the purpose of enabling warnings in the first place.

Comment: @Mysticial I was hoping the /Wall warnings would all be useless. Then I could just use /W4 and be happy. But it turns out /Wall also includes important checks such as "class has virtual functions, but destructor is not virtual".

Comment: Jeff, one trick I use is to use multiple compilers. I find GCC with pedantic makes a great broom if I just want to clean up code. I'll go back and build it with the correct tool chain for the project afterward.

Comment: @JeffM Then I suggest `/W4` and enabling the extra ones you want manually. The example you give with virtual functions and no virtual destructor will give lots of false positives for common design patterns like composition and trivially destructible inheritance. Which is probably why they aren't enabled at any warning level except `Wall.`

Comment: Part of the issue is that some of the compiler's internal workings, and the MS implementation of the standard library and STL, suppress warnings; this is usually because these actions would normally be unsafe or not recommended, but compiler quirks require that the compiler internally take these actions nonetheless.

Comment: Case in point: the [vector vbase constructor iterator, `__vec_ctor_vb`](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/msvc/language/compgen/_j.htm), a helper function used while constructing an array, when the element type is non-trivial and has one or more virtual base classes, generates (and suppresses) C4191; this warning is normally disabled, but `/Wall` enables it, exposing the programmer to unneeded implementation details.

Answer (score -1):

I looked up that warning and it pointed me to this list of warnings that are normally suppressed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23k5d385.aspx.

You can review that list and do global suppress of the warnings that you don't care about.  I'm not sure how to do a global suppress.  But that particular warning seems useless.

Found the link on how to globally suppress warnings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx.

Comment: I saw that page, and I figured if none of those warnings were important then I could just stick with /W4. But it turned out a lot of those are genuinely useful. For example, checking "class has virtual functions, but destructor is not virtual" is in that list.

Comment: This does not work, even if I specifically disable the warnings. e.g., 4514

Comment: @JeffM I think any compiler will have warnings that may not be useful.  But if you feel some are useful, just disable the ones that are not.  It's an infrequent task (also needs to be done when compiler is upgraded).

Comment: @AnonMail Yeah, that's starting to look like what I'll have to do. I'll start with /Wall then cherry pick disable the stuff I don't care about.