# Warning generated for empty main()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

I created a default empty project on VS 2015 and set the warnings to `/Wall`. I have a single source file with the following:

```
#pragma warning(push, 3)        
#include <functional>
#pragma warning(pop)

//#pragma warning( disable : 4710 )
int main()
{

}
```

I get the following errors:

```
1>c:\users\flatmouse\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\project72\project72\source.cpp(10): warning C4710: 'std::exception_ptr std::exception_ptr::_Current_exception(void) throw()': function not inlined
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\exception(299): note: see declaration of 'std::exception_ptr::_Current_exception'
1>c:\users\flatmouse\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\project72\project72\source.cpp(10): warning C4710: 'std::exception_ptr std::current_exception(void) noexcept': function not inlined
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\exception(358): note: see declaration of 'std::current_exception'
```

Next I tried keeping the warning level at 3 for all the source code by moving the pop to the last line:

```
#pragma warning(push, 3)        
#include <functional>

//#pragma warning( disable : 4710 )
int main()
{

}
#pragma warning(pop)
```

But I still get the same errors.

Why is a warning still reported?

Comment: /Wall strikes again ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603207/msvc-2015-wall-has-lots-of-not-useful-messages)).

Comment: [Someone ran across almost exactly this yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603207/msvc-2015-wall-has-lots-of-not-useful-messages). Wall is presenting trivial warnings in the includes even though you've blocked them with the lower warning level in the pragma above. Doesn't look like anyone had a good answer.

Comment: @RobertPrévost Yep. Queue the Pink Floyd.

Comment: The error says line 10 of `source.cpp` but the file you posted only has 9 lines.

Comment: @M.M Yes, I checked again and it only has 9 lines yet reports the error on line 10. If I double-click the error in the IDE it takes me to the first line. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Visual C++ use `/W4`, not `/Wall`. The latter is just asking for an avalanche of sillywarnings. It used to be that `/W4` would present an avalanche of warnings for the Windows API and C++ standard library headers, but happily that's no so anymore with Visual C++ 2015.